# background of progressbar show

Tags: android, bluetooth, progress-bar

I'm reading QR codes with a bluetooth device and every time find something simulates a "Enter" whenever I detect the Enter key runs show a ProgressBar. What I like to do is put the dark background transparent as when a dialog or something is released. I have not found a way to do so for a progressbar.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layoutLectorBluetooth"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/lectura"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_edittext"
    android:inputType="textFilter|textMultiLine"
    android:cursorVisible="false"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:lines="1"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="148dp" />



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/scan_trans" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textoEjemplo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:text="Escanea el E-ticket para validarlo."
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtValidando"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textoEjemplo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text=""
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/loader_prueba"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textoEjemplo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:indeterminate="true" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

onCreate Activity

```
    lectura = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.lectura);
    lectura.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent keyevent)  {
            //THIS!
    findViewById(R.id.loader_prueba).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Example

[image]

Edit

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things wrong with your approach:

1. The `@android:color/transparent` attribute actually is totally transparent as in no color at all. What you'll probably want is a slightly opaque black color
2. If you apply the `android:background` to the `ProgressBar` it won't actually cover the whole window, instead you'll have to add a new `View` that has both height and width set to `match_parent`

Edit: based on the full layout you posted now, I would add the following (inside the `RelativeLayout`):

```
<RelativeLayout> <!-- that's the one you already have -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/background_dim"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#42000000"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then you also need to set this `View` to visible when showing the `ProgressBar`:

```
findViewById(R.id.background_dim).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Yes, I wanted to add a new View but how to integrate it? that's what I do not like

Comment: You'll have to post the complete layout file then.

Comment: I've edited my original answer, any progress using this?

Comment: It works, but the images are very visible, almost above the same view. :(

Comment: Could you post a new screenshot so I can better assess the issue?

Comment: Where did you put the `View`? In the topmost position in the layout file or at the bottom? Also, you might want to set `android:elevation="5dp"` on the dimming `View` so it covers the `Toolbar` on Lollipop devices and higher.

Comment: No resource identifier found for attribute 'elevation' in package 'android'

Comment: Is your target SDK set to 21 or higher?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101889/discussion-between-sioesi-and-tr4android).